# Repo (GIT) how to update a manifest file when using a mirror?

Tags: android, git, repo

We initiated a repo locally using an existing manifest.

```
repo init -u ssh://ger-repository/my_project-manifests -m my_manifest.xml --mirror
```

Now, the manifest file changed. Running the init command is not possible:

```
fatal: --mirror not supported on existing client
```

How can we update the manifest without deleting all mirror folder and re-syncing again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be possible, considering [this patch](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/254709804d83d611831d4c78fe17280750e2eb2a%5E!/) which proposed to replace that error message with:

```
fatal: --mirror is only supported when initializing a new workspace.
Either delete the .repo folder in this workspace, or initialize in another location.
```

If this is about the same repos, but with a different URL, then [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/repo-discuss/lS34iKQtxiY/Ge7tHND-OaoJ) mentioned:

> If you've been able to clone all the gits you're almost there, just use
>   the insteadOf trick on the clients if the relative URLs aren't available
>   in the manifest you're mirroring.

```
[url "https://yourserver.example.com/"]
        insteadOf = https://android.googlesource.com/
```

Comment: can we try to fetch the manifest file (manually) before running the 'repo sync'?

Comment: @DimaKreisserman Maybe: that would avoid the init step and the error message.